# Server and client authentication: How can I create a Firebase Auth Token from server and send it to the web client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to authenticate my users using email and password from the server, using firebase and sending the token generated to the client.

In the server-side, I'm using a nodejs **firebase function**, and the token is created using the **firebase rest auth API**, using the **verifyPassword** endpoint, then I use the token generated and send it to the client.

I'm using in the client **firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)** to try to sign in, but I get me a **invalid token response**.

What I'm trying to do is allow to authenticate the user in both sides, the server, and WebClient
.

Is this possible or there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can send your Client-Side idToken to your server, as described in the [Firebase Auth Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) and on your server you can create a Session-Cookie with firebase admin

```
admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn})
    .then((sessionCookie) => ...
```

I have a project where i send the idToken to the server when the Auth-State changes on my Client-Side:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
          sendTokenToServer(idToken,csrfToken);
        });
      } else {
        clearCookiesOnServer(...);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to change my authentication approach

Comment: @lombardo -- Need a help here. how are u sending token to server with sendTokenToServer() ? and also from where are you getting the idToken and csrfToken.

Comment: I'm using an ajax post to make a request to the server for creating a session cookie. The idToken is returned by getIdToken, then sending as a part of the request; for the csrfToken i am using the csurf package https://github.com/expressjs/csurf